# Change options in select box

Tags: jquery

two select boxes,second select box options should change depending on what you chose in first. how can i do this with jquery?

```
<select class="units">
    <option value="1">Sve ponude</option>
    <option value="2">Srbija</option>
    <option value="3">Grcka</option>
</select>
<select class="units">
    <option value="1">Sve ponude</option>
    <option value="2">Novi Sad</option>
    <option value="3">Beograd</option>
</select>
```

Comment: See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/yt568kkb/1/)!

Comment: i need to change option text in second select.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gco5gpL1/ look at this fiddle

Comment: like if srbija in first,in second novi sad,beograd and if grcka in first,in second atina,krf.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: i don't know how to do that. i know what @Pekka did,but don't know how to change option text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var one = ['Madison','Janesville', 'Green Bay'];
var two = ['Sacramento', 'Los Angeles', 'San Fransisco'];
var three = ['Richmond', 'Roanoke', 'Harrisonburg'];

$('#ddl1').change(function(){
    //clear values
    $('#ddl2').html('');

    //find which list to use
    var list = [];
    switch($(this).val()){
        case "1":
            list = one;
            break;
        case "2":
            list = two;
            break;
        case "3":
            list = three;
            break;
    }

    //populate dropdown
    $.each(list, function(index, value){
        $('#ddl2').append("<option>"+value+"</option>");
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b1nygzxm/

Comment: This is what i need. but can there bee options on load? just one option like  chose city or something like that.

Comment: one more thing... can value of options be the same as text?

Comment: This code wont work with this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jznpuf5j/). i cant see why....

Comment: I'm sorry I'm having a hard time following your code

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('change', '.units', function () {
    var a = $('.units option:selected').val();

    alert(a);
    $('.units1').val(a);

});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gco5gpL1/)**

`UPDATE`

***[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xa258b03/3/)***

Comment: i need new options. for srbija they can stay the same,but for grcka i need new ones.

Comment: what do you mean?new ones?

Comment: add new options and remove old.

Comment: @DejanJankov if this is the answer yick the check for future reference

Comment: @godmode made code more suitable form mi site. But this code would work to. i will up wote it.